# [Ubuntu 16.04]How to disable black flash animation when taking screenshots?

Tags: screenshot

Now 1 a.m (GMT +7) I'm coding with maximum-but-not-playing headphones. My laptop has the <kbd>prtsc</kbd> key near the <kbd>delete</kbd> key. I pressed <kbd>prtsc</kbd> accidentally... jumped out of my chair and nearly had a heart attack.

That flash animation + loud screenshot sound are the scariest thing I have faced in my life.

Anyone please save me!!

EDIT: Thanks for the link about how to disable sounds. I edited title. I'm not yet clear how to disable black flash or black fade(I don't know how to call it) animation when taking screenshots. Any suggestion?

Sorry for my bad English!

Comment: You probably can't. That doesn't sound to me like something that's going to have a setting anywhere. It might be better just to remap the printscreen key.

Comment: My current solution is using i3wm. Both increase productivity and ignore these effects

Comment: Agree - this is terrible!! I jump on my chair every time I hit that key by accident.. geez, no one responsible for this ever realized this?! :/